# Алгоритм поиска билета для автобусов

Tags: java, алгоритм

Пишу приложение для поиска и продажи билетов на автобусы. Но столкнулся с трудностью составления алгоритма поиска билетов. Буду рад любому совету и помощи, или ссылке.

Задача такова: у нас есть расписание, которое состоит из рейсов. Рейс создаётся как ежедневный или по числам или дням недели. Рейсы по одному маршруту, но в разное время отправления считаются разными рейсами(например, рейс 111 в 8.00 и рейс 117 в 10.00).

Как организовать поиск билетов от станции А до станции Б, т.е. найти все рейсы идущие через эти станции, причём направление от А до Б, наоборот не подходит.

**Обновление:** Есть рейсы, которые состоят из:

- номер рейса;
- его маршрут от станции А до конечной станции Б;
- тип рейса (ежедневный, по дням недели, по числам).

Каждый рейс содержит таблицу графика его движения по маршруту: время отправления и время прибытия на каждую станцию остановки, но это все без даты, т.к. рейс ходит например ежедневно. Есть рейсы обратные от станции Б до станции А, есть проходящие рейсы через станцию А и станцию Б.

Как можно организовать поиск билетов, а значит рейсов, которые идут, например 11.06 от станции А до станции Б, причём дата прибытия на станцию Б 12.06?

Comment: Если в рейсе нет информации о том, какие остановки он в себя включает, то никак. Ну а если есть, то в чем проблема? Ищем все рейсы, которые подходят по времени и включают в себя две эти остановки

Comment: В таблицах системы обязана существовать таблица графиков движения рейсов, где для каждого рейса хранятся все узлы этого рейса с временем прибытия и убытия. Выбрать из такой таблицы записи, где для рейса присутствует оба пункта, причём убытие из начального узла маршрута раньше прибытия в конечный выполняется запросом практически тривиальным. В общем, не вижу проблемы. И уж тем более не вижу необходимости рожать какой-то там алгоритм.

Comment: Узлы времени есть, т.е. Время прибытия и отправления на каждую станцию (остановку), но время, например 8.00-8.30, и есть только дата отправления, например рейс отправляется 11.06.19 в 23.00, а как тогда определить остановку на станции А1 в 0.20, это уже другое число (12.06)

Comment: Постарайтесь как можно подробнее описать имеющуюся в системе информацию. Расскажите как хранится каждый отдельный рейс, перечислите все поля, составьте как можно более реалистичный пример (только не слишком большой).

Comment: Есть Рейсы, которые состоят из: номер рейса, его маршрут от станции А до конечной станции Б, тип рейса (ежедневный, по дням недели, по числам). Каждый рейс содержит таблицу графика его движения по маршруту: время отправления и время прибытия на каждую станцию остановки, но это все без даты, т.к. Рейс ходит например ежедневно. Есть Рейсы обратные от станции Б до станции А, есть проходящие Рейсы через станцию А и станцию Б. Как можно организовать поиск билетов, а значит рейсов, которые идут, например 11.06 от станции А до станции Б, причём дата прибытия на станцию Б 12.06?

Comment: *например рейс отправляется 11.06.19 в 23.00, а как тогда определить остановку на станции А1 в 0.20, это уже другое число (12.06)* Таблица графика движения содержит не абсолютное время прибытия/убытия, а относительное по отношению к времени начала рейса, причём если время в пути более суток, то в графике будут значения более 24 часов. Так что в таблице рейсов будет 11.06.19 23:00, а в графике движения этого рейса для станции А1 там будет 01:20. Для получения абс. времени их придётся сложить, получив 12.06.19 00:20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пока не видно в чем проблема, тут скорее задача на аккуратность и усидчивость. Попробую расписать свое понимание процесса по шагам:

**Задача:** Определить все рейсы, которые отправляются из А в дату ДатаА и прибывают в Б в дату ДатаБ.

**Шаг 0.** У нас есть список всех рейсов.

**Шаг 1.** Выберем рейсы, которые проезжают через А.

Пробегаемся по всем рейсам, отсеиваем те, у которых в маршруте нету А.

**Шаг 2.** Из оставшихся, рейсы, которые проезжают через Б после А.

Отфильтровываем рейсы, у которых в маршруте после А нет Б.

**Шаг 3.** Из оставшихся, рейсы, которые проезжают через А в ДатаА.

Тут нужен некий метод, который умеет:

- находить А в маршруте рейса;
- находить диапазон времени, в который рейс должен отправиться со стартовой точки, чтобы прибыть в А в ДатаА;
- проверить, отправляется ли рейс в этот диапазон, используя тип рейса (ежедневный наверняка может всегда, для еженедельного потребуется проверка).

Если тут может быть несколько дат отправления для одного рейса, то имеет смысл разбить рейсы на сущности *КонкретныйРейс (Рейс, ДатаОтправления)*.

**Шаг 4.** Из оставшихся, рейсы, которые прибывают в Б в ДатаБ.

Для каждого из рейсов вычисляем дату прибытия в Б. Те, по которым дата не сойдется с ДатаБ отбрасываем.

Для этого шага будет удобно если *КонкретныйРейс* будет уметь рассчитывать время прибытия на заданную станцию в своем маршруте.

Это общий подход, который можно реализовать по шагам и проверять после каждого шага. После того как реализация будет хорошо проверена на корректность можно будет подумать о скорости выполнения. Если рейсы будут хранится в БД, то часть шагов (если не все) можно будет выполнить запросами.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @lutsik Пожалуйста! Удачи в реализации :)

Comment: @lutsik галочку ставить не забываем